# Facebook login in android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have one  android app where I need to do post which goes on facebook wall.

In my tablet-phone I have installed Facebook app, but when I do post ,it will open facebook login popup, and will not facebook app login.

Please help me I want open facebook login popup with in app.

My code:

`facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());`

Comment: show your complete code.

Comment: _private Facebook facebook;_

Comment: facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

Comment: @user3292920, not like this go to edit and edit your full code again and then post.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use facebook sdk for facebooklogin and posting ,here is the example ,where you will get your complete solution

[here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)